# URL Decoded Prior to htaccess Rewrite Rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rule in .htaccess :-

```
RewriteRule ^.*/-y.* /handleurl.php [L]
```

Its purpose is to display appropriate pages depending on the values in the url, for example:

`example.com/books/BookA/-y?act=x` will display bookA page

the variable holding the book name is encoded such that ...

`example.com/books/Book B/-y?act=x` becomes `example.com/books/book+B/-y?act=x`
... which is fine (it's decoded in `handleurl.php`)

however if the book is called `Book A/B` I have ...

`example.com/books/Book A/B/-y?act=x` which becomes `example.com/books/Book+A%2FB/-y?act=x`

It appears that htaccess decodes this before the rewrite rule, so the rewrite rule sees too many elements in the URL delineated by the `/`.

Is there any way I can get the rewrite rule to ignore the encoded `/` as intended?

I have seen a previous response to a similar question, but I only need the `/` to be ignored, not other encoded characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It appears that htaccess decodes this before the rewrite rule, so the rewrite rule sees too many elements in the URL delineated by the `/`

This is not the problem. Regardless of whether the URL-path `/books/Book+A%2FB/-y` is decoded or not makes no difference here<sup>***1**</sup>. Both would match the (rather generous) regex `^.*/-y.*` in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

<sup>(***1** But yes, the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is URL decoded, ie. %-decoded.)</sup>

The problem is likely to be that Apache (by default) rejects - with a 404 - any URL that contains a %-encoded slash ie. `%2F` (or backslash `%5C`) in the URL-path portion of the URL. This is a *security feature*, that otherwise "could potentially allow unsafe paths" ([source](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes)).

However, this can be overridden with the [`AllowEncodedSlashes`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) directive. But this directive can only be used in a *server* or *virtualhost* context. It cannot be used in `.htaccess`.

You either need to set `AllowEncodedSlashes On` to allow encoded slashes, which are also decoded, as with other characters.  Or set `AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode` to permit encoded slashes, but do not decode them - which is preferred and probably what you are expecting.

---

*Aside#1:*

> ```
> RewriteRule ^.*/-y.* /handleurl.php [L]
> ```

The regex `^.*/-y.*` is very generic, possibly too generic. This is the same as simply `/-y`. What is the `.*` after `-y` intended to match? From your example URLs it looks like `-y` is always at the end of the URL-path, so this could be anchored, eg. `/-y$`. And if the URL that you need to match always starts `/books/` then maybe this should also be included in the regex?

---

*Aside#2:*

> ...the book name is encoded such that ...
>
> `example.com/books/Book B/-y?act=x` becomes `example.com/books/book+B/-y?act=x` ... which is fine (it's decoded in handleurl.php)

This isn't strictly "URL encoded", you have *converted* the *space* into a `+` in the URL-path. The `+` is a valid "URL encoding" for a *space* when used in the query string only. A `+` in the URL-path is a literal `+` (and will be seen by search engines as such). In the URL-path, a *space* would be URL encoded as `%20`. (You may have used the wrong PHP encoding functions, eg. `urlencode()` instead of `rawurlencode()`?)

Of course, you are free to convert/encode the URL however you wish to create a more readable URL - providing it's valid.

Comment: Mr White, thank you. I was clearly barking up the wrong tree. The Not Found [url] message I was getting was I think as you suggest due to Apache not liking the encoding of /. I take out that bit of encoding and it works (albeit the next program fails with the additional / - but that is due to poor design which I can now fix. I will also try and improve simplify the rewrite rules as per your notes.

Answer (score -1):

The rewrite rule was never the problem. I think it was Apache not liking the encoded '/' and the fact that the downstream url handling program was using '/' as a delimiter when identifying the individual url elements. I have to work out: 1) whether I want to allow '/' in the variables that make up the elements of the freindly url, and 2) if so how to pass it without upsetting Apache and how to subsequently disect the url. Maybe I will convert '/' to '~' for the benefit of the URL then convert back to '/' prior to subsequent display. Thank you Mr White.